# DataTable update existing row issue ajax

Tags: jquery, datatables-1.10

I have an ajax response like the following,when a jquery dialog is submitted

```
<tr bgcolor="" id="row_4">
  <td><p>ffwrwrqwrvqwerf</p></td>
  <td>Active</td><td><a href="" class="link_btn"  id="4_edit">Edit</a> | <a href="" class="link_btn"  id="4_delete">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

I need to modify the Datatable row `#row_4` to the ajax response.

```
// msg is the variable which stores the ajax response.

 $('#lstCategories').DataTable().row($('#row_'+$('#formid').val())).data($(msg)).draw();
```

This is giving me an error .
When I place variable `msg` instead of `$(msg)` in the statement `$('#lstCategories').DataTable().row($('#row_'+$('#formid').val())).data($(msg)).draw();`
,it gives me '<' in first td,'t' in second td ,'r' in third td but without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your ajax result already has the `<tr>`. So you can delete the particular row and you can add a new row

Please check the demo code

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myTable').DataTable();

        $("#editButton").click(function () {
            var tbl = $('#myTable').DataTable();
            tbl.row("#row_2").remove().draw();
            var tblRow = "<tr id='row_2'><td>Value 3 - edited</td><td>Value 4 -edited</td></tr>";
            tbl.rows.add($(tblRow)).draw();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css" />
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Title 1</td>
            <td>Title 2</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="row_1">
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row_2">
            <td>Value 3</td>
            <td>Value 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row_3">
            <td>Value 4</td>
            <td>Value 5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<input id="editButton" type="button" value="Edit" />
```

Comment: This code is for addi ng a new row to the DataTable. I need to update a row on click event .The click event response contains <tr> tag.Example ,I need to modify the second row with <tr><td>value 5</td><td>Value 6 </td></tr>

Comment: @Techy, Hi I have edited the code. Please check now. You can delete the existing row and add a new row. The Row will add in the exact index position of the existing row.